# Insert a new line string on every blank line in python

Tags: python

What I am trying to accomplish is to insert a new line for blank every line in a text file.

I know this can be done with a simple editor but what am really trying to do is to add an incremental value to each of the added lines.

This is my code so far:

```
import fileinput
import re

count = 0

for line in fileinput.input():
    line = re.sub('\n\r', '\n\r\n\rmyline' + str(count), line.rstrip())
    count+=1
    print(line)
```

For some reason, I cannot replace newline with my content. Also tried just /n or /r but with no success

Live example:

Initial text file:

```
line1
line2

line3


morelines
```

End result:

```
line1
line2
myline1
line3
myline2
myline3
morelines
```

Comment: Line endings differ between OSs.

Comment: I'm using python on windows but I have also tried different forms of new line regex expression. Moreover, if I do this regex replace in notepad ++ it works like a charm, just that I cannot add the incremental number

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This works for me

```
def get_my_line(line_no):
    print("myline {}".format(line_no))


path = 'test.txt'
f = open(path)
i = 0
was_prev_text_new_line = False
for foo in f.readlines():
    if (foo.__eq__("\n")):
        if (was_prev_text_new_line):
            i += 1
            get_my_line(i)
        was_prev_text_new_line = True
    else :
        print(foo.replace("\n", ""))
        was_prev_text_new_line = False
        i += 1
        get_my_line(i)
```

The logic here is :
-> get_my_line is the function which gives/prints the required lines to be added/printed based on the var 'i'

->'i' is incremented every time we call get_my_line

-> f.readlines reads every new line and stores in foo (i.e '\n' is detected by it)

-> if foo is '\n' it means , we have a non-text-containing-line.

-> The approach here is to add new line after each statement and if the foo is '\n' only then check if the prev txt read was '\n' or not (this helps us to skip the first '\n' after the text-containing-lines, and for the subsequent continuous '\n', we can add new lines)

-> if was_prev_text_new_line is true then call get_my_line and increment i

-> set 'was_prev_text_new_line' true at the end of the if block

-> if foo is not ('\n') then simply print foo , get the new line to be added and increment i

Comment: It would be nice if you could explain your approach to the OP so that he can understand why it works for you without having to decipher your code.

Comment: Yes, an explanation would be great but just for the record this indeed works

Comment: added explanation , kindly see if the explanation seems satisfactorily or not

Comment: Thank you for your explanation!

Answer (score 0):

There are several issues with your code.

1. The Python default when reading text files is to translate CR LF to `'\n'` on input, so your code won't ever see `'\r'`.
2. The newline representation on Windows is CR LF (carriage return + line feed), not LF CR. If anything you should've been using `'\r\n'`, not `'\n\r'`.
3. Except you're looking for empty lines, i.e. two newlines in a row, so that should've been `'\n\n'` (or `'\r\n\r\n'`).
4. The string you're transforming is `line.rstrip()`. `rstrip` removes all trailing whitespace including `'\n'` and `'\r'`, so your regex will never match anything even if you change it to `'\n'`.

Untested:

```
import fileinput

count = 0
for line in fileinput.input():
    if line.rstrip() == '':
        count += 1
        print('myline' + str(count))
    else:
        print(line, end = '')
```

Comment: 1. So how can I read blank lines with python? 2. I always use \r\n  when searching for newlines in windows notepad++ so \n\r was just another try to make this work 3. This is what happens when you copy the code and don't know exactly what it does. Bottom line, your code helped me a lot just that now it adds **myline** to every line in my file and not just for the new lines as expected. Sory for not making it clear from the start - I edited the question. In notepad++ I make this by replacing \r\n with \r\n\r\nmyline

Comment: @dozenme What do you mean by "just for the new lines"? How do you distinguish between "old" and "new" lines?

Comment: It should be "just for the blank lines" instead of "just for the new lines" meaning the lines that have nothing more than a carriage return

Comment: @dozenme Your example shows `myline1` being inserted between `line1` and `line2`. There is no blank line there.